# How can I open a file in Eclipse on Mac OS X if I have its full Unix file path?

Tags: macos, mac, eclipse

I have a full unix file path like:
/etc/var/www/temp.txt

How could I open this up in Eclipse on OSX with one shot?  When I go to file open it has no place for a full directory path?

Comment: what version of eclipse? a screenshot of the open dialog would help too.

Answer (score 3):

So long as you're using the Cocoa version of Eclipse is when you are on the open dialog, press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> and enter the UNIX path to the parent folder of the file. You can then select the file.

Unfortunately `open -a` does not work with Eclipse.

Comment: What's Cocoa?  CMD-SHIFT-G doesn't work on my version.

Comment: MikeN: When you download Eclipse for the Mac you're offered it three flavours; Carbon, Cocoa 32-bit and Cocoa 64-bit. In this case, they are more or less they are different wrappers (versions of SWT) between Eclipse and interacting with the host operating system. (http://superuser.com/questions/31749/cocoa-vs-carbon-versions-of-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

8.5 years later, this now works on the latest Eclipse.

```
open -a Eclipse /etc/var/www/temp.txt
```