# How do I download C++ IDE for mac?

Tags: mac, cocoa

I have a mac High Sierra, version 10.13.6. I want to install c++ IDE Eclipse on my mac, am I able to download the software for mac cocoa? Does my mac run on mac cocoa? How do I find out?

Comment: Installing the most recent version of Eclipse should work, actually.

Comment: what is mac cocoa?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API). As there isn't really anything else right now it's not as important as a term as it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

See [Cocoa vs Carbon versions of Eclipse](https://superuser.com/questions/31749/cocoa-vs-carbon-versions-of-eclipse?rq=1) for some details about Cocoa vs Carbon, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)) for an non-technical explanation of the Cocoa API. Introducing Cocoa was an important step for Apple when moving to OSX, nowadays it's basically the only UI API supported by the OS.

So in your case you can download any "Mac Cocoa" package from [Eclipse Packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).